# lodash isEmpty can not pass ts check

Tags: typescript, lodash

lodash isEmpty can not work well with typescript check rules:

Typescript error:

**Object is possibly 'undefined'.**

```
    126 |   public isActive(item: IMenuItem) {
    127 |     // We assume routes should follow a well naming convention (e.g. parent: '/user', children: ['/user/mgmt', '/user/accounts'])
  > 128 |     if (isEmpty(item) || isEmpty(item?.children) || isEmpty(item?.children[0])) {
        |                                                             ^
    129 |       return false;
    130 |     }
    131 |     // all children should
```

Ts version: "4.4.4"

Comment: I think you can try to find an answer from here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/45521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably too much for the TypeScript compiler to resolve.

No need for the multiple tests though. You can just do:

```
 if (isEmpty(item?.children?.[0])) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Your answer has a flaw there. If `item.children` is `[]`, it will pass `?` check but it has no items which makes an error on `[0]`

Comment: @NickVu How so? [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllApgWxgXhgbwFAxsACzgBsATAJ0TAC4YBtAXWwF9tsAzAVzGCjnHgQAosgAOUAJ4AKAB61uAazAgA7mACUWXDEpRO5MDACEMgNws2cdjClxhYybaTIA-ADpCJClXd0ADAzqmjh4oJAgxIhuxCAA5lIA5CjiEgnq5sxAA)

Comment: Ohh this case is pretty interesting in Javascript, it's an empty array but still can access index values like `[0],[1],[2]`. Today I learn a new thing, thank you~

Comment: It will just return `undefined` if there's no value at that index.